# Unable to change country. Tried everything

Tags: google-play-store

I had made some purchases on my daughter's US credit card initially when in US. So my location was tagged as US. Recently when I tried to download one Indian app from India, it was showing not available in your country.
So I removed my daughter's credit card, added my Indian card and also made a purchase on my card.
Still Google Play is not changing my country.
Pl help.

Comment: what app are you trying to install??

Comment: Reliance jio ----- my jio

Comment: Also Citibank in

Answer (score 0):

The settings you have to change are at Google Wallet. Sign in with your account, go to Settings, and change "Home address" to your new address.

You might also have to change your phone number, and your default "Billing and delivery address" in the second tab.

So, there are TWO places where you have to update your address, and the settings do not usually take effect immediately.

From Google Groups :

You can update your home address whenever you want, including changing to a different country. If you're representing a company, enter your business address.

1. Sign into your Google Payments account at payments.google.com and click the Settings icon in the top corner. See screenshot:
2. Click Edit next to the "Home Address" listed and update the address (please note this is different from the "Address Book" which holds shipping addresses).
3. Open the Play Store and navigate to any item available for download.
4. Click to begin a download until you reach the "Accept and buy" screen (no need to complete the purchase)
5. Close the Play Store and clear data for the Google Play Store application (Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Clear Data) or clear your browser cache
6. Re-open the Play Store. You should now see the Play Store that matches your default payment method’s billing country.

Note that if you don't immediately see the Play Store that matches your default payment method's billing country, it may take a few hours for this to take effect.

If you haven't yet added a payment method to your account for the first time, add a card directly from the Play Store with a billing address that matches your intended country location. Then, follow steps 3 through 6 to show your intended country's Play Store.

Some things to note...

For legal reasons, you'll need to sign new Terms of Service if you change your home country.
1. If your Google Play balance is higher than these [amounts](https://support.google.com/wallet/answer/6034846), you won't be able to change your home country. If it's under those amounts and you change to a country with a different currency, you won't be able to see or use your remaining balance until you switch back to a country where that currency is used.
2. If you have a Payments Balance higher than USD $10, or a Checkout Merchant account, you won't be able to change your country.